# JPA Error generation classes

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using JPA with eclipselink to generate entities from tables, but the problem is that the foreign key in ManyToOne cases is not managed by JPA. I'm using Postgres database.I added code  below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Commande\"")
@NamedQuery(name="Commande.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Commande c")
public class Commande implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="\"idCmd\"")
private Integer idCmd;

@Column(name="\"idClt\"")
private Integer idClt;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Client
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    })
private Client client;

public Commande() {
}
```

Comment: so why don't you add a @ForeignKey?

Comment: I have this error : " Join column "client_"idClient"" cannot be resolved on table "Commande"   "   in the @ManyToOne

Comment: it must be like : @JoinColumns(name="idClt"), but it does not accept that !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just add: 
     @JoinColumn(name="\"idClt\"",insertable=false, updatable=false),
 it works now !